# How can I use PHP/HTML to display a random image as a background image

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to learn how to build a website. I've built the index page and here is the PHP and HTML.

```
<?php
session_start();
$png = array('png1.jpg', 'png2.jpeg', 'png3.jpg', 'png4.jpg');

$random = rand(0,4);
$picture = "$png[$random]";
?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS where I link to the image file:

```
body{
  background-image: url('png1.png');
}
```

I'm running the site on replit.com and here is the `png1.jpg`:

[image]

The background image is not appearing. Only the form is showing.
the link of website on replit is
https://htmlphpcssjavascript-login-system.gepingyi.repl.co/

you can view the code with inspect

Comment: Your English isn't very clear which makes it hard it understand what you're asking. Please rewrite your question.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to try generating a random background image using PHP but then do nothing with that, unless somehow you are hoping that it will exist within your stylesheet? As the stylesheet is a `.css` file any PHP code within will not be executed by the server so to have a dynamic style you could simply add an inline style tags to the page that sets the body background

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $png = array( 'png1.jpg', 'png2.jpeg', 'png3.jpg', 'png4.jpg' );

    $random = rand(0,count($png)-1);
    $picture = $png[ $random ];
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='index.css'>
        <style>
            body{
                background-image:url(<?php echo $picture; ?>);
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='login.php' method='post'>
            <label>Name: <input type='text' name='name' /></label>
            <label>Password: <input type='text' name='password' /></label>
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Thinking that perhaps the above, being untested, had an issue overlooked when writing the answer I have just put together a working example using images on my system &/or on the web.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    
    //local images within subdirectory
    $png = array( 'bck1.jpg','bck2.jpg','bck3.jpg','bck4.jpg','bck5.jpg','bck6.jpg','bck7.jpg' );
    $random = rand(0,count($png)-1);
    $picture = './images/' . $png[ $random ];


    // globally accessible images on interwebs
    $png=array(
        'https://undsgn.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ltotbngnzzu-uai-1600x900.jpg',
        'https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/54/86/cU6JWo.jpg',
        'https://cdn.nimbusthemes.com/2017/09/09233338/Free-Nature-Backgrounds-Sunset-by-Pixabay.jpg',
        'https://img.youtube.com/vi/V-FgQ2NAGFc/maxresdefault.jpg'
    );
    $random = rand(0,count($png)-1);
    $picture = $png[ $random ];

    

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        
            body{
                /*
                    If the background image is to entirely cover the available space
                    and maintaining the aspect ratio is not important then you can
                    set the size as below. Other settings ( such as cover or 100% auto )
                    will cause blank space when image bounds are reached
                */
                background-image:url(<?php echo $picture; ?>);
                background-size: 100% 100vh;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
            }
            
            form{
                width:300px;
                padding:1rem;
                border:1px solid silver;
                background:white;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                border-radius:1rem;
                box-shadow:0 0 25px white;
                margin:2rem;
                font-family:monospace;
            }
            
            label{
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                justify-content:space-between;
                align-items:center;
                background:white;
                margin:0.25rem 0;
            }

            [type='submit']{
                width:100%;
                padding:0.5rem;
                margin:1rem 0 0 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='login.php' method='post'>
            <label>Name: <input type='text' name='name' /></label>
            <label>Password: <input type='text' name='password' /></label>
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above, when saved with a `.php` extension will yield output like this:

[image: example]

Comment: thank you so much to answer sir, i indead trying make random back ground ,but it did't work, so i thought it's the problem with the php.So i use one picture to test first, but it seem didn't work too.

Comment: @james - Your comment is very unclear. Did this answer help you or not?

Comment: I aplogize for making the comment not clear, but the answer does not help me.The html does not showing the background anyway.

Comment: and here is the link https://htmlphpcssjavascript-login-system.gepingyi.repl.co/

Comment: i will be glad to fix for me, I've stuck at there for already one week.

Comment: In the linked to webpage I can clearly see PHP code in the page source (right-click, page source ) - which suggests that this is **not** being parsed/processed by the server or that the page has a `.html` extension rather than `.php`.... is that the case?

Comment: When I tested `index.php` it returns 404 yet `index.html` is OK. You **must** save the files with `.php` extension unless you do some trickery with the server config ( probably beyond your level of expertise just yet )

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your image is not showing or if it is showing in the wrong place.

using the css below you will allow you to set your background image properly.

```
 body {
      background-image: url('png1.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;  
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: it still didn't seem to work, maybe it's the problem with replit.com?

Comment: here is the link for my program in replit.com

Comment: https://replit.com/@GepingYi/htmlphpcssjavascript-login-system#index.css

Comment: https://htmlphpcssjavascript-login-system.gepingyi.repl.co/

Comment: Where is png1.png located? Is it in the same directory as your php file? If not, you should reference it with the correct path (relative or absolute).